# Magmi activates products in all category-levels

Tags: magento, magmi

I am using the Magmi On the fly category creator/importer plugin to import products and create categories into a Magento 1.7.0.2 installation. That works fine, but there is something I did not expect.

All products were assigned into all created category-levels. Even when I try the samlpe CSV-snipped from the [wiki](http://sourceforge.net/apps/mediawiki/magmi/index.php?title=On_the_fly_category_creator/importer#Basic_example)

```
sku;name;attribute_set;store;categories
"100";"Product 1";"Default";"en";"My Products/Sample Products/Sample Category"
"101";"Product 2";"Default";"en";"My Products/Other Products"
```

When I try the above CSV, product with SKU 100 is active in cat "My Products" and "Sample Products" and "Sample Category". Product with 101 is active in cat "My Products" and "Other Products".

Is this the default behavior or is there a trick to activate the product only in the last named category of the category-level?

My config is:

- Magento V. 1.7.0.2
- Magmi V. 0.7.18
- Plugins:
- - CSV Datasource (1.3) by Dweeves On the fly
- - category creator/importer (0.2.3) by Dweeves Image attributes
- - processor (1.0.25) by Dweeves On the fly indexer (0.1.5) by Dweeves
- - Standard Attribute Import (1.0.5) by Dweeves

Comment: Ignore this stupid question!!! I have found the relevant point in the plugin-config. Sorry!

Answer (score 0):

This is the default behaviour of the "category creator/importer" plugin.
But you can change it to only activate the product only in the last category level.

This can be done either through the web interface:

---

Go to /magmi/web/magmi.php

Click on the "configure" button of creator/importer

Select "last category of each branch" next to "Assing product to";

---

Or if you for some reason feel like editing the config files directly.

---

Browse to the conf directory and make sure that this line is included:

CAT:lastonly = "1"

in the "CategoryImporter.conf" file